# Decoding JSON - Notice: Undefined offset: 0

Tags: php, json

I'm trying to get the value of bitcoin received and the time it was received in the most recent transaction for some bitcoin address using the blockchain.info API. The API displays transaction data in JSON format when requesting a URL like: https://blockchain.info/address/btc_address?format=json.

The response (up until the first transaction) looks like:

```
{
    "hash160": "-",
    "address": "-",
    "n_tx": 11,
    "total_received": 1,
    "total_sent": 1,
    "final_balance": 1,
    "txs": [
        {
            "ver": 1,
            "inputs": [
                {
                    "sequence": 1,
                    "prev_out": {
                        "spent": true,
                        "tx_index": 1,
                        "type": 0,
                        "addr": "-",
                        "value": 1,
                        "n": 1,
                        "script": "-"
                    },
                    "script": "-"
                }
            ],
            "block_height": 1,
            "relayed_by": "-",
            "out": [
                {
                    "spent": false,
                    "tx_index": 1,
                    "type": 0,
                    "addr": "-",
                    "value": 1337,
                    "n": 0,
                    "script": "-"
                },
                {
                    "spent": true,
                    "tx_index": 1,
                    "type": 0,
                    "addr": "-",
                    "value": 1,
                    "n": 1,
                    "script": "-"
                }
            ],
            "lock_time": 0,
            "result": 0,
            "size": 1,
            "time": 123456,
            "tx_index": 1,
            "vin_sz": 1,
            "hash": "-",
            "vout_sz": 2
        },
    ... more txs ...
    ]
}
```

I filtered the data because it's not relevant. The only number I want to retrieve is the value `1337` shown in the first `out` of the first `txs` and also the time `123456` of the first `txs`.

So my PHP looks like this:

```
$result = json_decode(file_get_contents("https://blockchain.info/address/$bitcoinAddress?format=json"));
$lastPayment = $result->txs[0]->out[0]->value;
$lastPaymentTime = $result->txs[0]->time;
```

This code works fine but I am getting the notice of `Undefined offset: 0`. I don't want to hide PHP notices but why am I even getting it? Can I not reference the JSON array with indexes? Why not and how else do I get the first element in the JSON array? I don't really want to use a loop...

Thanks!

**Edit**: My editing of the JSON above might cause some confusion... View the full JSON for a BTC address at https://blockchain.info/address/1NTZMU7yKshvWiZYuMquJUHuzusFLZ8SMZ?format=json

**Edit 2**: Fixed the problem... One of the BTC addresses I was using caused the notices because it hasn't received any bitcoins and so the `txs` array was empty...

Comment: That is not proper JSON as shown, you would need an array wrapper `[]` around all of the first level objects (of which you are showing one plus `...` for additional ones).  Nevermind, just ran through jsonlint and realized your `...` probably are supposed to men additional txs elements.  I editted your post to give better formatting

Comment: which line gives undefined offset?

Comment: Both the second and third lines (in my PHP code) give the errors. I am also getting `Notice: Trying to get property of non-object` on both of these lines as well...

Comment: Hm, not getting any notices here. Do you `include()` something?

Comment: Please check the value of $bitcoinAddress. There is no problem with your current code, assuming of course, that $bitcoinAddress is correctly assigned. For me, it works fine.

Comment: Ahh I feel dumb. My script checks the balance of multiple BTC addresses stored in a database and one of them hasn't received any bitcoins so the `txs` was empty... Fixed it now. Thanks!